# Value from return, into a Google maps function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, google-maps, meteor

I want to be able to set the center of a Google Map based on coordinates stored in a Mongo collection.

I use Meteor as framework. Inside my Template.Home.helpers, I have the following function to get the coordinates:

```
mapCenter: function () {
  return (this.map); //returns -37.8136, 144.9631
}
```

How can I pass this value into this mapOptions function, also inside the same template helper:

```
mapOptions: function() {
    // Make sure the maps API has loaded
    if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
      // Map initialization options
      return {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(XX.XXXX,XX.XXXX),
        zoom: 8
      };
    }
  }
```

Can I store mapCenter as a variable and put it into the center in the mapOptions function?

Answer (score 0):

Four basic options:

1. Save the coordinates into a *Session* variable then pick them up later
2. Save the coordinates into a *closure*
3. Save the coordinates into a *reactive variable*
4. Save the coordinates in a document in a collection

Session variable example:

```
mapCenter: function () {
  Session.set('coordinates',this.map);
  return (this.map); //returns -37.8136, 144.9631
}

mapOptions: function() {
    // Make sure the maps API has loaded
    if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
      // Map initialization options
      return {
        var coord = Session.get('coordinates');
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(coord.latitude,coord.longitude),
        zoom: 8
      };
    }
  }
```

This approach has some limitations however since your *Session* variable is global in scope. If the user has multiple tabs open with multiple maps then you might end up with all the maps being the same. Then a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) might be better.

Comment: As you stated, I do have multiple maps. Each document in the database has it's own coordinates, and so Session is maybe a bad idea.

How about returning a database lookup into the current document?

Comment: Sure, if you have a document you're tracking anyway then writing to it and reading from it is even better and will be plenty fast.

Comment: How would I get my Mongo query into the Google maps function?

Comment: Assuming that in `mapCenter` you have something like `myCollection.update({ _id: myId },{$set: { coordinates: this.map }});` then in your `mapOptions` code you could just have `var coord = myCollection.findOne({ _id: myId }).coordinates;`